# How to scale a div on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
.ham-layer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}



#nav-icon {
    position: fixed;
    left: 35px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 20px;

    margin: 50px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 9px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-icon.open span {
    background: #111111;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -1px;
  left: 1px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 22px;
  left: 2px;
}

#nav-icon.open .ham-layer {
    -webkit-transform: scale(100);
    -ms-transform: scale(100);
    transform: scale(100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ham-layer"></div>
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-bars hamburger"></i> -->
                    <div id="nav-icon">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <p id="_intro" class="text-center"></p>
                    <hr width=40%>
                    <p id="belowIntro" class="text-center"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I wanted to make it so that when the hamburger icon is clicked, the layer scales itself up thus showing the menu. But the scaling part is not happening. What should I do so that this happens? Right now the hamburger icon is animating but the circular div isn't expanding.

Comment: add your html markup or a jsfiddle would be better, much better

Comment: `$(this)` is referring to the `$('#nav-icon')`, but what you really want is something like `$('.img-circle').toggleClass('open')` based upon your css.  But it is hard to tell without the HTML.

Comment: Should I add full html page or is this good?

Comment: You want to scale the element to 100 times it's previous size...that seems like a ***lot***!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your .ham-layer is not inside of your #nav-icon.  Your last CSS selector `#nav-icon.open .ham-layer` implies that .ham-layer is somewhere inside of your #nav-icon div.

Comment: If I put the .ham-layer inside nav-icon, and add this line: $('.ham-layer').toggleClass('open'); below $(this).toggleClass('open');  , it expands but the hamburger animation is broken. Why would that be?

Comment: You can either move your ham inside of the div, or use jQuery to edit the .ham-layer separately on click.  I don't think you can select just the previous sibling div with css.

Comment: It messes up because of the :nth-child selectors.  nth-child doesn't count the nth span, but spans that happen to be nth-child(x), so you need to change them to 2, 3, and 4 now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, removing the .ham-layer outside of nav-icon worked for me. Now its doing exactly what I wanted :)